# Get list of Cities/Towns from State/Province using the Google Geocoding API

Tags: javascript, api, geocoding

How does one use the Google Geocoding JS Api to get a list of Towns/Cities within a certain Province?

The reason I ask is because in a register form, the user selects country, then a list of provinces are shown and then once a province is clicked, I want to present a list of towns in that province.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted this isn't part of the Google Geocoding API, however you could do it yourself with a database of cities & towns with their associated state/province. A simple AJAX request to your server database would be able to return the cities and towns when your user selects a province.

I found this database for cities and towns by US state, but I am sure there are similar databases available for most countries. http://www.farinspace.com/us-cities-and-state-sql-dump/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of the Geocode API. The goal of it is to provide the ability to convert latitude/longitude into a recognized city, state/province, country set, and conversely in the Reverse Geocode API.